# Calculate the integral by using differentiation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

We have the integral:

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1-e^{-ax^2}}{x^2}dx$$

First I need to prove that it is continuously differentiable.

So I checked the limits:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}f(a,x) = a$$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(a,x) = 0$$
So looks like $f(a,x)$ is continuous from $0$ to $\infty$.

Then I checked the derivative with respect to $a$:

$$\frac{d}{da} f(a,x) = -e^{-ax^2}$$

And we also see that derivative at x to $0$ is $-1$ and when $x$ to $\infty$ it is $0$,

So then I need to $|\frac{d}{da}f(a,x)| \leq h(x)$,

where $\int_0^{\infty} h(x)dx$ exists.

I see that $|\frac{d}{da}f(a,x)|\leq 1 \leq h(x)$

So now I need to find $h(x)$. I can't seem to find that...

(Then after I proved the upper I would use: $F'(a) = \int_0^{\infty}\frac{d}{da}f(a,x)dx \implies F(a) =\int\int_0^{\infty}(\frac{d}{da}f(a,x) \,dx) da $)

However I need help with finding $h(x)$....

Comment: Hello :) Do you want to calculate the integral or just like to show, that it's finite?

Comment: @Jochen I need to do both, so first show that by the steps: The function bellow the integral is continuous, then that the derivative is continuous, then that we can have $h(x)$ such that the derivative of the function bellow the integral is bounded by it. And then when I calculate $F'(a)$ I need to integrate it back, to get the original integral

Comment: @Jochen If you have any better options please tell, but the main idea that I need to use is the upper

Comment: It holds $\frac{1-e^{-ax^2}}{x^2}\leq\frac{1}{x^2}$.

Comment: @Jochen But can't for very very small $a$ and $x$ the left of the inequality be a very large number, specially because we are looking at the absolute value?

Comment: Apologies: the partial derivative wrt $a$ is $e^{-ax^2}$

Comment: @Jochen For example $a = 0.000001$ and $x = 0.000001$ the inequality $|\frac{1-e^{-ax^2}}{x^2}|\leq \frac{1}{x^2}$ will not hold

Comment: Well now you have a correct derivative, it is clearly integrable since the Gaussian integral is well known to converge - do you know of it? Btw, once you’ve done your Feynman integration, the correct answer is $\sqrt{\pi a}$

Comment: No, Jochen’s inequality is correct. It should be applied to the interval $[1,\infty)$ to show convergence there, and you must use a different inequality to show convergence on $(0,1)$. Hint: the function is monotonic, and you know the limit as $x\to 0$.

Comment: @FShrike No we haven't taken the gaussian integral yet:(...

I see it converges there. However how to show that the derivative also converges by bounding it '

Comment: Well, the derivative’s integral converges on $(0,1)$. On $[1,\infty)$, the derivative is less than $e^{-ax}$ which is even more well known to converge as an integral since it has a clear antiderivative. There’s your bound. Study the Gaussian, and then you’ll get $\sqrt{\pi a}$ by following through on the Feynman integration (for $a\gt0$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\varphi(a) = \int_0^l \frac{1-e^{-ax^2}}{x^2}dx$, the function inside the integral is obviously continuous in both $x$ and $a$ (we don't need to worry about $x=0$ since we can assume $x>0$ without changing the value of the integral) thus we can differentiate under the integral sign to obtain:

$$ \frac{d\varphi(a)}{da} = \int_0^l \partial_a \frac{1-e^{-ax^2}}{x^2}dx = \int_0^l \partial_a \frac{x^2e^{-ax^2}}{x^2}dx = \int_0^l e^{-ax^2}dx$$
Taking the limit $l \to \infty$ we get:
$$ \dfrac{d}{da}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1-e^{-ax^2}}{x^2}dx = \int_0^{\infty}e^{-ax^2}dx = \dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{a}}$$

Integrating with respect to $a$:
$$ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1-e^{-ax^2}}{x^2}dx = \sqrt{a\pi}$$

You can verify numerically that this works.

Answer (score 4):

It is interesting to look at the generalization
$$I_n=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1-e^{-ax^n}}{x^n}\,dx$$ Doing the same as @Juan F., we have
$$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-ax^n}\,dx=a^{-\frac 1n} \,\Gamma \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$ and then
$$I_n=a^{\frac{n-1}{n}}\,\frac{n  }{n-1}\,\Gamma \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$ which is valid even if $n$ is a real.

For large values of $n$
$$I_n=a \Bigg[1-\frac{\log (a)+\gamma -1}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\Bigg]$$

Comment: ⧫ étonnant! $\to $

Comment: @DarshanP.. In what sense ? Cheers :-)

Comment: For more generalization? like $n$ than $2$